# Community rejected edits displayed as "rejected" is misleading

Tags: feature-request, edits

Community rejected edits are displayed as .. "rejected".

For example `user 5061 had 110 edit suggestions approved, and 10 edit suggestions rejected` is displayed when clicking `(more)` in a [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7740386) review (i don't know if it is displayed elsewhere too).

This is quite misleading since the reviewer got his edit rejected because it conflicted with a subsequent edit, not because his edit wasn't good.

Change it to something more descriptive, like "conflicting edits".

It'll display more accurately the editing skills of users, and feel more rewarding for editors.

Comment: So you're suggesting having three stats for editors? Approved, rejected, conflicting? And what good will "conflicting" do? Just make you feel better? It's not misleading- The edit was _rejected automatically_ by the system due to another edit. So since it was _rejected_, no matter the reason, I would think keeping it in the rejected count makes far more sense than keeping track of it alone.

Comment: @Kendra: We have disputed, declined, and helpful flags, why not extend the same consideration to suggested edits? Semantically, "rejected because the system wasn't smart enough to automatically merge" is *in no way* similar to "rejected because multiple human reviewers considered it a bad change".

Comment: @Kendra "_keeping it in the rejected count makes far more sense_" - No it doesn't. It makes no sense. "Rejected" can be used as a measure of editing skills. When messed up by conflicting edits, it becomes a less useful statistic. Also, it's not about *me* feeling better. It's about how SO works; making users feel good when seeing their "trophies".

Comment: I agree with @user5061 - the only logical purpose of showing reviewers a particular user's number of rejected edits would be to be an indicator of their historical edit quality, and including edits that were rejected not based on quality but due to a logistical technicality don't seem relevant to that purpose.

Answer (score 21):

I have just made my 110th suggested edit so I may make a good case study.

Currently I am listed as having 110 suggested edits with 10 being rejected.  Of those rejected edits:

- 1 was rejected by a user
- 9 were rejected by Community for conflicting with a subsequent edit

This means that **90%** of my rejected edits were out of my control.

In fact, of the 9 Community rejected edits:

- 0 were rejected because a 2k+ user made a better edit
- 5 were rejected because a 2k+ user made essentially the same edit
- 1 was rejected because a 2k+ user made a *worse edit*
- 3 were rejected because the original author made an edit

I considered a better edit to be one that changed substantially more than my edit. A worse edit was one that changed substantially less than my edit. The large majority were simple code indentation fixes or grammar/spelling errors that both my and the conflicting edits addressed.

I have a **9%** reject rate for my suggested edits, because of conflicting edits, even though my *true* rejected edit rate is **<1%**.

Community rejected edits should not be displayed as rejected edits.

My thoughts on potential solutions are:

- Remove the accepted/rejected stats entirely as they are misleading
- Create a disputed category for edits
- Force subsequent edits to either accept or deny pending edits

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't be adding screenshots of text.

Comment: @BSMP good to know. I just assumed an actual image is always better than a link to an image. What is the correct thing to do when someone posts a question with a link to a screenshot of text?

Comment: You can either leave a comment asking them to edit the question to include the text itself or, if you're up for it, adding in the text yourself.

Comment: Or flag to close.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic agreed.
Another solution I would consider the best would be to not reflect conflicting edits in the stats at all.. since they have neither been approved, nor been rejected by anybody, they just came it at the wrong moment and shouldn't be counted therefor.

Answer (score -14):

I don't think this is worthwhile, for a couple reasons.

First, and less important/mostly a matter of opinion and conciseness, I don't see what purpose this actually serves. By matter of fact, the edit *was* rejected. It was *automatically rejected* by the system. So, I still find "rejected" to be a fitting category for these edits.

More importantly, *good edits* also get manually rejected and *bad edits* also get manually approved.

Pulling these stats out doesn't make them any more meaningful. I can't say how common good edits being rejected is, but I wouldn't be surprised to hear that it was incredibly common for bad edits to be approved.

Basically, there's really no good reason to separate these out when the data isn't completely trustworthy anyway. I've had edits that I made that I thought, later, really should've been rejected. They were unanimously approved. *Whenever* I make an edit, I actually watch to see if anyone I am sure understands the queue approves the edit. If I see a name, or stats, of anyone that seems to actually know how the queue works, and they approved the edit, then I feel like it must've been a semi-decent edit.

The editor stats are basically meaningless. I more support removing them from the edit page completely, as was suggested in the comments, than I do putting dev time to make an inaccurate and untrustworthy stat no less inaccurate or untrustworthy. If devs put any time or effort into this, just remove it.

Even if the stats were 100% accurate, including this feature request, what purpose would they serve? A good editor can make a bad edit, and a bad editor can make a good edit, so they shouldn't even be taken into account (not that they can atm) for the purposes of deciding how likely the edit is to be good. There's no reason to display this at all.

Comment: "The editor stats are basically meaningless". I agree. Bad edits are accepted and good edits are rejected. We can take a step towards fixing the latter by not classifying valid but conflicting edits as rejected.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic I meant good edits are _manually_ rejected. Because that happens too. I'll clarify my post. I really don't think _slightly_ fixing broken stats is at all worth it. I'd rather just see the stats gone, since they are meaningless.

Comment: I would agree that removing the stats all together is a solution. But as long as the feature exists I think it is important to address it's problems. Classifying good edits as rejected (manually or otherwise) is a problem as long as the accepted/rejected stats exist.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic But what point is there in fixing it slightly when it will _never_ be 100% accurate? Even implementing this feature request will still leave the stats highly broken. It's not _at all_ worth the dev time to fix. That's my whole point- Fixing something from broken to still broken is worthless. If anything's done, it should jsut be getting rid of the state. Otherwise, there are more important things for the devs to work on.

Comment: I don't think this would be "fixing it slightly". From my answer below, 90% of my rejected edits were not rejected through review. For someone actively pushing edits to be reviewed, adding this feature could be the difference of appearing to have 1 in 10 bad edits vs. 1 in 100 bad edits. While the review process may not be perfect, this feature would make the good/bad edit stat *significantly* more accurate. Whether the good/bad edit stat should be shown at all warrants its own discussion.

Comment: You're _a single_ data point. My stats, for example, wouldn't change _hardly at all._ Just because it would fix the stats majorly for you does not mean that it will necessarily completely fix everyone's. _And_ all it will "fix" for you is making you look a bit better. What about the users who have their good edits rejected manually? Won't help them. What about the editors who get their bad edits approved often? Their stats won't change. It's still fixing it _slightly._

Comment: This only matters for people <2k rep as they are the ones who must be reviewed. As long as those users are encouraged to edit this is more than a slight fix. As for yourself, 3 of your 5 rejected edits were rejected by the community. You have very few suggested edits but on the few you do have we can still see Community is responsible for a disproportionate amount of rejects. I only gave my self as an example but the trend is clear on almost anyone actively pushing edits to be reviewed.

Comment: Two data points does not a conclusion make, and 2 rejects versus 5 in 58 is _really_ not that big an improvement, especially if those 3 aren't now classified as "approved", they're more just "Meh, ignore these." You've not convinced me any further that this fix is worth it. Moving these from "rejected" to "ignore these" does _nothing_ for _anyone_ when this stat doesn't even matter for anything. Good day.

Comment: Either the stat should be removed, or it is wrong and an attempt to fix it should be made. You cannot argue that it is simultaneously so broken it needs to be removed and also fine the way it is. As for more data points, I counted Community rejected edits / total rejects for the users who originally commented on this post. Fermi 6/9, Sam 3/5, Nathan 15/30. Community accounts for more than 50% of rejected edits on every user I have seen so far. A relatively simple fix would make the rejected edit stat *significantly* more accurate. Or the stat could be removed. Leaving it alone seems wrong

Comment: I'm advocating removal of the stat- I've clarified that, since I can see how it might not look that way. I don't see a point in fixing it, if devs put time towards this, they need to just remove it.