# Distinction between peer reviewed rejection of edits and automatic rejection of conflicting edits

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

Edits by users with a reputation of 2000 or more are automatically accepted and do not have to be peer reviewed. The consequence is that (better or worse) not yet reviewed conflicting edits of users with a lower reputation are rejected. These automatically rejected edits are summed up with all edits which are rejected after peer review.

1. Does the number of rejected edit suggestions have any influence (despite other users seeing and maybe reacting to it)?
2. Wouldn't it be better if the total number of rejected edits of a user would distinct between automatically rejected edits and peer reviewed rejected edits?

Comment: For part 1 of your question, yes. If you have too many rejected edits in a short span of time, you'll be temporarily blocked from suggesting edits. However! Edits rejected due to editing conflicts _do not_ factor into this. As for 2, I feel like this has been asked before...

Comment: I was not succsessful finding a question covering 2, if anyone has more luck it would be much appreciated. Thanks for answering 1, @Kendra .

Comment: Also, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290903/community-rejected-edits-displayed-as-rejected-is-misleading).

Answer (score -1):

Despite this being an old question, I support both points of @rostbot.

You file an edit and get the notification about the last edit being rejected. I wonder why it was rejected and see said message about being rejected in favor of a conflicting edit. If it does not count towards the "bad-edit-lockout-threshold" it's ok for me.

What bugs me is, that these rejections are counted to the total of rejected edits on the profile. Not that I strive for a "perfect record" but looks like a user creates bad edits and the "bad edit count" is raised artificially.