# formatting edit denied after user edited question and not shown in history

Tags: discussion

See my edit suggestion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9558880

It originally only added formatting to the question, which the question did a terrible job at, but since it was within the first few minutes, the edit history doesn't show what the user edited from. The user also coincidentally added the same formatting I was suggesting but also changed `event` and `entity` around. Notice my edit suggestion is also titled "formatting" yet doesn't appear to change the formatting at all due to being compared to the wrong revision. The `event` and `entity` edits were something the user edited after my suggested edit. Then the user themselves denied my edit suggestion.

I feel my edit suggestion at the time was a good suggestion. Is there any way to prevent this type of thing from occurring in the future? Also can I dispute my edit suggestion being marked as "denied" since I feel it wasn't denied but rather my suggestion was for a certain revision and after the user edited their question, I feel my edit suggestion should be marked as void not denied, since the user edited their post and made my edit redundant, just like people can't suggest edits on posts when another edit suggestion is pending. Yet with my edit suggestion, it was for a revision before the user directly edited their post.

Is there a way to dispute this or compensate for it with some kind of countermeasure in the software?

Comment: I'd just move on. Sometimes people are unreasonable.

Comment: What Pekka said. Also, quick tip for Meta: don't go into hyperbole.... it won't help... "violated" is REALLY too strong a word here...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't edits made by another person *always* generate history?  That is to say, there isn't a grace period for those edits?

Comment: I'm saying the original poster edited their own question when I put in an edit suggestion, and since it was within the grace period, the edit history doesn't show what their question originally read. Also having enough reputation, they reviewed my edit suggestion and denied it.

Comment: That makes sense.  Any edit done to a post can be superseded by either the OP (automatic), or anyone else that says, "Reject and Edit".  Had the question *dramatically* changed in this period or were there simple wording/phrasing changes?

Comment: I'd say the post was in dire need of formatting changes, because without them, the entire post was corrupted, since significant HTML code the user was trying to show us was getting lost due to post rendering rather than displaying the code which we needed to see, which would have easily gotten 3 approvals.

Comment: Sorry. Being *violated* is what happens when someone is raped or a child is molested. Having your feelings hurt because the original poster didn't accept your edit is not being *violated*. Grow up, learn that you don't always get everything you want, and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently only two end states for suggestions. They can either be accepted, or rejected.  Anything that's not accepted, for any reason, is rejected, including conflicting suggestions that the software is unable to automatically merge.

In this case, though, the user manually rejected the suggestion, which was binding because they're the post owner, and there's nothing the software can really do about that except switch who's responsible for the rejection.

*If* the Community ♦ had rejected instead because of an edit conflict in the grace period, and *if* edit conflicts were [handled specially (like disputed flags)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290903/community-rejected-edits-displayed-as-rejected-is-misleading), then you might get something useful, but those are separate feature requests.

Comment: I believe the system should be built better to deal with revision conflicts. What if someone had enough reputation to directly edit and their revision conflicted? I believe this is a software fault.

Perhaps submit the revision hash (since the grace period allows revision 1 to be changed) which the user was editing along with the edit suggestion, so if the post is edited within the few minutes it takes for someone to suggest an edit, that the user will be shown the current version and asked if they still want to continue submitting their edit due to a revision conflict.

Comment: @Ultimater: If someone had 2k in this case, I believe their edit would go through confusingly; there are other circumstances in which a warning is shown instead, or edits are even [flat-out blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256386/conflicting-tag-only-edit-hard-stops-me-from-submitting-drafted-edit) until the editor is reloaded. Fixing edits to incorporate a full conflict merging system is probably not going to happen any time soon, though.