# Why is my conflicted edit counted as rejected suggestions?

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits

I'm a little bit confused about my [latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9790468) which was rejected, due to a conflict. Now I've got an other rejected edit, which somehow reflecs badly on me.

[image]

Like [this Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277900/5038873) says:

> Automatic rejections due to an editing conflict do not count.
>   Rejections because a reviewer used the Reject and Edit button do count
>   towards a ban.

So if my edit was not good, why didn't the reviewer corrected at least the errors which I corrected:

AnyBody -> anybody

fuction -> function

thanx -> thanks

I'm not sure if I should edit the answer again or what I've done wrong.
Could anybody explain it to me? Did I edit the question to much?
I am unsure what to do in future edits.

Somehow this [question includes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290903/community-rejected-edits-displayed-as-rejected-is-misleading) what I mean, but it does not have a proper answer.

But still I don't know why my edit was rejected and the question  still has lots of mistakes.

Comment: The conflict didn't come from the review queue (it it had, would have a "Reject and Edit" or "Improve"). The person who made the edit did not see your suggestions, they made the edit independently.

Comment: It doesn't reflect badly on you in any way. Conflicts like this happen. If you want to try improving that question again, feel free to suggest another edit, but I think you'd be wasting effort polishing a turd.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks a lot, so basically the Editor stats contain rejections which do not mean anything bad (due to auto rejections like this) and other rejections due to inappropriate edits right?

Comment: You should have removed "thanx" or "thanks" or any variant thereof completely (not fixed the spelling) - unless, of course, it's part of a code sample. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)