# Are edits which are accepted by the OP listed as his edits?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I have [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22216526) *[Calling a slide panel with CSS and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708551/calling-a-slide-panel-with-css-and-java)* with some effort and then my edit request was canceled because the OP has made an edit - which is the same as mine?

I'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: Afaik, your edit and ops edit are not exactly the same. I guess your edit was canceled because op submitted an edit themselves around the same time you edited.

Comment: Your edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22216526) because it conflicted with the OPs edit.

Comment: And your edit didn't touch the title, which is patently wrong. Nor the tags, which are kinda terrible. And not convinced that question can be salvaged, although I do not have the patience to really go through it right now.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, edits accepted by the OP are listed as your edits. However, your edit was never put up for review, because it conflicted with another edit.

If an edit *conflicts* with an edit, it's rejected. That means that your edit is discarded and no longer visible, even though you possibly made a good edit. This is what happened in your case.

Edits conflict if another person made a substantial edit to the post before you submitted your edit.

If you make an edit and someone else submits a substantial edit within the period of you making it, it's automatically rejected. The quality of the edit is not assessed at all.

[This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290903/7296893) talks more about *rejected* not being the right term for these edits, because they may in fact be very good edits. But terminology doesn't really matter here.

Comment: A messy case that would benefit from the not-uncommon 'edit lock' request that surfaces on Meta sites from time to time...